# Help when SMTP server hangs when sending emails from Java

Tags: java, email, smtp, queue

I use an external mail server to send SMTP mails, this server is effectively beyond my control.

A couple of times recently this mail server has had issues and it's caused my Java (Struts/Spring) app to completely hang when waiting for a reply from the mail server.

I'm using the Spring **org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender** to send mails.

When the external mail server is having issues it's the following line that freezes **mailEngine.send(mailMessage);**

I don't mind that sometimes emails don't get sent but how can I stop this from freezing my application while it waits for a reply from the SMTP server?

Are there any good email queuing solutions for Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can send the emails in a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thread your calls to the SMTP server. You can make use of the [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (various implementations exist) and drop in `Runnables` to be executed at a later stage (out of band). The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to explicitly code your threading model.

If you collect the [Future](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/java/online/jdk/150/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object from the Executor upon submission, you can call `get()` with a suitable timeout and cancel (and perhaps re-submit/retry) upon timeout.